# gulp-watchで監視しているフォルダ内で日本語フォルダを入れるとエラーでストップ

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

gulp-watchで監視中のフォルダに新しくフォルダを作成してリネームした場合、ENOENTエラーが出て監視がストップしてしまいます。
日本語のフォルダ名を使用しないという対応ではなく、
できれば、気軽にフォルダを追加できるようにしたいです。

OSはMacとWindowsの両方で試しました。
nodeのバージョンはv0.12.5　gulpのversionは3.9.0です。

Comment: OSは何ですか? node のバージョンも。そういう情報があると確度の高い解答が得やすくなります。

Comment: 取り急ぎ、MACに関しては、gulp.watchを使わずにgulp-watchを使うことで、監視がストップする状況は回避出来ました。Windowsがまだ上手く行っていないため、Windowsで上手くいく方法分かりましたら、回答に追加したいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

MAC&WINDOWS両方のOSで、問題が解決いたしました。

```
    gulp.watch
```

を使わずに

```
    gulp-watch
```

という[プラグイン](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch)を使うことで、監視がストップする状況は回避出来ました。

【2015/07/01追記】WINDOWSの場合、フォルダの削除でエラーが発生して監視がストップしてしまいます。
【2015/0702追追記】WINDOWSでフォルダ削除時にエラーが発生して監視がストップしてしまう件ですが、gulp-watch制作者が以前、別件で回答している内容で理解いたしました。

> vinyl-file is not about directories (as gulp itself), so events forcreateanddeleteon directories are not emitted. If there is any files in this directory - then you will getunlink ` event for these files.

[gulp-watch制作者の回答](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/70)

MACの場合は、ディレクトリごと削除してもエラー発生していなかったのですが、
WINDOWSの場合は、ファイルを全て削除した上で、フォルダを削除すれば、上記エラーの発生を回避できました。